Opening gnome-terminal tabs with commands
I have used gnome-terminal for years to open tabs like this:
gnome-terminal --window \
--tab-with-profile=Server-prod --geometry=200x24 --title server1 --command "ssh server1" \
--tab-with-profile=Server-prod --geometry=200x24 --title server2 --command "ssh server2"

In that example I would have two tabs, one logged into server1, the other logged into server2.  However recently it has been warning me:
# Option ?--command? is deprecated and might be removed in a later version of gnome-terminal.
# Use ?-- ? to terminate the options and put the command line to execute after it.

I can't seem to get that syntax to behave correctly.  If I do this:
gnome-terminal --window --tab-with-profile=Server-prod --geometry=200x24 --title w1lxingprd1 -- ssh w1lxingprd1

It runs the same command in the new window (the first tab) and the added tab.  Further, if I try for multiple tabs:
gnome-terminal --window --tab-with-profile=Server-prod --geometry=200x24 --title w1lxingprd1 -- ssh w1lxingprd1 --tab-with-profile=Server-prod --geometry=200x24 --title w1lxingprd2 -- ssh w1lxingprd2

It just starts and exits immediately.  Is there a way to achieve the effect of the old --command using the new syntax?

I found the answer on Baeldung's web site (section 6).  In summary:

Create a shell script with the tabs you want in separate lines: gnome-terminal --tab --bash -c "the commands you want"
Run that shell: gnome-terminal --window -- bash -c your-script

Not as straightforward as the old method, but probably more flexible.
